# Not being able to run pylint using windows (7) command prompt

Tags: python, pylint

I've just installed all the dependencies (asteroid and logilab-commons) and pylint, ran the tests for pylint and they all passed, but i just cant get pylint to work... i keep getting

> 'pylint' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

while running in the command prompt.

im not sure what im doing wrong and i cant seem to find any explanation anywhere

Comment: Did you check your path? Sounds like CMD.exe can't find the script.

Comment: tried it in cmd and in powershell, tried different paths, what path should i try to use? shouldn't it work the same way 'python' does? i mean just write python (in any path, and you're in)?

Answer (score 1):

> set PATH=%PATH%;C:\python27\scripts

is apparently what i needed to make it work... thanks for the path direction.